# Why are spin 1/2 baryons less massive/energetic than spin 3/2 ones?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, baryons

I am just wondering why the lower spin state multiplets for both baryons (when looking at $L=0$ and considering only the u d and s quarks) are lower in energy i.e. the 1/2+ multiplet is lower than the 3/2+ multiplet. This might well be obvious but I can't seem to come up with an argument for why it is the higher spin state that is the excited state. It is the same situation with mesons and the 0- and 1- multiplets.

When I look for an analogy with the two electron helium atom in atomic physics the differences in energy of different spin states arrises due to differences in symmetry in the spatial part of the wave function which in turn alters the electromagnetic potential and hence alters the energy but I can't really see a similar argument here.

Comment: I think it has to do with Pauli exclusion principle. Three quarks with the same spin have to have different energy levels and thus the total energy is higher.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! It sounds like it might be along those lines, the only thing is that not all the particles are made of identical quarks e.g. in the meson multiplets a pion vs a rho meson they are comprised of a quark and an antiquark and therefore are distinguishable so I'm not sure whether the Pauli exclusion principle applies?

Comment: Just an outline of an answer: in few-body strong systems, isospin symmetry matters as much as, if not more than, angular momentum.

Comment: Okay thanks I think I'm getting closer. I'm now thinking that as an overview if we have two identical quarks present the spin part of the wavefunction changes from antisymmetric to symmetric between the ½+ and 3/2+ groups. Since identical fermions are antisymmetric on exchange this makes the flavour (or isospin) part change from antisymmetric in the ½+ group to symmetric in the 3/2+ group (the spatial and colour parts remaining unaffected). This difference will lead to a change in strong potential of the two states and a mass difference.

Comment: I then presume that in cases where the quarks are all distinguishable (such as mesons or uds baryons) the spin part changing forces a change in the flavour part which in turn leads to a different strong potential and mass difference. I'm not completely convinced but it feels like it's getting there